# Check image url using javascript async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, es6-promise

I've seen multiple questions like this here but all of them just use `alert` or `console.log` as the result and I have a different problem.

I'm trying to verify if an image url is valid using `async/await` and `axios`.

```
async function checkImageUrl(imageUrl) {
  let result = false;
  const promise = await axios.get(imageUrl);
  promise.then(() => {
    console.log('result TRUE');
    result = true;
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log('result false');
    result = false;
  });
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

the image urls are in a json array. I use this in another function like this:

```
let imageValid = false;
someJson.some((obj) => {
  if (obj?.image != null) {
    imageValid = checkImageUrl(obj.image);
    console.log(imageValid);
    if (!imageValid) return true;
  }
  return false;
});

if (!imageValid) {
  return;
}
```

I've used some `console.log`s  to check the results. The problem is I never see those logs in async function and `console.log(imageValid)` always prints a `Promise` object in console. Is can't figure out how to implement this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `async-await` in some function. You can use tradition for-loop. Same time you can clean up the `checkImageUrl` function

```
function checkImageUrl(imageUrl) {
  return axios
    .get(imageUrl)
    .then((x) => true)
    .catch((x) => false);
}

async function main() {
  let imageValid = false;
  for (let index = 0; index < someJson.length; index++) {
    const obj = someJson[index];
    if (obj?.image != null) {
      imageValid = await checkImageUrl(obj.image);
      if (imageValid) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!imageValid) {
    return;
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: The big hint was `You cant use async-await in some function.` Though I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
async function checkImageUrl(imageUrl) {
  let result = false;
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(imageUrl);
    result = true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("result", result);
  return result;
}

(async () => {
  let imageValid = false;
  someJson.some((obj) => {
    if (obj?.image != null) {
      imageValid = await checkImageUrl(obj.image);
      console.log(imageValid);
      if (!imageValid) return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  if (!imageValid) {
    return;
  }
})();
```